# netbios McAfee HIPS block

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, netbios, mcafee

All across my network random computers have been receiving a ton of McAfee HIPS blocks that state "Blocked outgoing UDP Source *random IP* netbios (137) destination *IP*". The only way we can resolve this is by putting the computers in rule exception which we can't have for long so essentially the computers are useless. I have already verified their place in DNS and DHCP and have ensured no duplicate IPs or hostnames exist. Any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Do* the computers spill out those packets? Check with wireshark or tcpdump (ideally using a monitor port on a switch) If yes, you may have a "unwanted software" problem. Windows does no send "random ip" packets, even with UDP.

Comment: I've used terminal monitor on the switch of the computer with the issue however I never have seen denials appear. When refreshing HIPS activity there are 5-10 more errors each time I press refresh consecutively.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "terminal monitor", but you will have to *trace that packets* to be sure if they are real and where they are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Ports 137 138 139 are traditionally NetBIOS over TCP. This is obsolete in a network capable of modern SMB with DNS over IP.

[Disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/direct-hosting-of-smb-over-tcpip), in the network stack of Windows hosts, or via a DHCP option. Anything that requires NetBIOS to function is likely quite old and requires special attention to secure.

Comment: I was able to disable it through the network controls however after restarting the computer we still get the same blocks. Is there a way to do this via the port instead? All of our blocks show ports 137/138.

Comment: Capture packets, examine them, and do some tracing (procmon) to determine what the hosts are doing.